# Access static variable outside of class or non static variable change in public void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

i got this script:

```
public static bool noTitleTrigger = false;
static GameObject shop;

static GameObject player;
String col;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
    shop = GameObject.Find("Shop");
    shop.SetActive(false);
}
```

Then this as a public void that i called in a OnClick() button.

```
public void StartShop() {
    noTitleTrigger = true;
    shop.SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log("Log");
}
```

This is in another script to check the variable `noTitleTrigger`

```
if (titleScreen == true && gm.noTitleTrigger == false && firstTouch.position.y > Screen.height / 8) {
    titleScreen = false;
    title.enabled = false;
    buttons.SetActive(true);
}
```

I get this error if `onTitleTrigger` is static:

> Assets\Scripts\CanvasManager.cs(36,48): error CS0176: Member
>   'GameManager.noTitleTrigger' cannot be accessed with an instance
>   reference; qualify it with a type name instead

If i dont do a static `onTitleTrigger` variable then the value of it doenst change by the public void StartShop();

Any help would be great :D

Comment: gm is the GameManager from where the other scripts are

Comment: Well, do you need it to be static or not? That matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (titleScreen == true && gm.noTitleTrigger == false && firstTouch.position.y > Screen.height / 8) {
```

To this:

```
if (titleScreen == true && GameManager.noTitleTrigger == false && firstTouch.position.y > Screen.height / 8) {
```

What the compiler is telling you is that you are trying to access the static variable `noTitleTrigger` through an instance of `class GameManager` (`gm.noTitleTrigger`). When you use `gm = AddComponent<GameManager>()` or `gm = GetComponent<GameManager>()`, `gm` is the **instance reference** the error mentions.

Since the member is **static**, you should instead access it through the type that contains it (`GameManager.noTitleTrigger`).

Comment: Just as a sidenote but not relevant for the correctness of this answer: This is Unity. Components like OP's `GameManager` are not instantiated via `new` but via Editor built-in methods like `AddComponent` or `Instantiate`

Comment: Thank you, @derHugo. Definitely worth noting.